# JSF navigation handling?

Tags: spring, jsf

I'd like to ask what todays best practice of writing page navigation is for web pages with JSF 2? For now I only know defining the return strings of my backing beans, which are then mapped to the according url's. `@Controller`, `@RequestMapping` and so on.

But now I'm looking for something especially decoupling backing beans and navigation handling.

Would it be worth to take a look into Spring webflow?
Or is there better / easier?

ty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jsf 2.0 has what is called implicit navigation. It works like this: if an action result matches a view id (ie jsf page), the navigation will take you to that view. You don't really need any annotations for that.

Comment: Ok, that’s a really neat feature in jsf2.

But one more question: Often even in Spring 3.x sample apps I see `@Controller` with many navigation handling (`@RequestMapping`) and so on. What are these good for, and why do people use them so often?

ty

Comment: Those are Spring MVC annotations. Those follow a different web application paradigm in comparison to JSF. There's a thread about that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136295/spring-compared-to-jsf-2

Answer (score 1):

PrettyFaces is very good library for management of navigation in JSF, and SEO friendly, intuitive URL addresses. Navigation can be configured using annotations or in separate XML file. I use this library whenever I can.

http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great reference to JSF2 navigation, I use it all the time!

http://mkblog.exadel.com/2009/09/learning-jsf2-navigation/